# C++ Lining up spacing with single and double digits

Tags: c++, arrays

I am programming a program that shuffles a deck of cards. I got it to work and I want to display the cards before the shuffle and after the shuffle. I am having a spacing issue dealing with the number 10.

I know that I can use the `"\t"` but is there any other way.

**A snippet of Output:**

```
A of Spades
2 of Spades
3 of Spades
4 of Spades
5 of Spades
6 of Spades
7 of Spades
8 of Spades
9 of Spades
10 of Spades
J of Spades
Q of Spades
K of Spades
```

I'm almost sure that it is the `assignDeck()` that is causing this issue, but I will include both.

```
void assignDeck(string *suit, string *cards, string *deck)
{
    int p=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<13; j++)
        {       
          deck[p] = cards[j]  + " of " +  suit[i];
          p++;
        }
    }
}
void showDeck(string *deck)
{
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
      cout<<deck[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll always have this space issue. You need to add extra spaces to fill up this drawback. This is because 10 has one more extra character.
If your total string length is 11 when single digits are used, the length becomes 12 if one more digit is added so the spaces are moved and the length also increases.

Comment: You'll find this a lot easier if you're not passing string pointers everywhere, but actual numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are outputting the entire line as one string, you can modify your cards string while adding it to deck.

```
void assignDeck(string *suit, string *cards, string *deck)
{
    int p=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<13; j++)
        {   
          if ( cards[j].size() < 2 )
            cards[j] = " " + cards[j];
          deck[p] = cards[j]  + " of " +  suit[i];
          p++;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is only so that you have minimal changes to your code. For a general case I would suggest you use the `std::setw` function in the `<iomanip>` header.

Comment: Modifying the name string just to solve a formatting issue is bad practice in my opinion.

Comment: Yes it didn't seem nice to me either :(. I was about to add this.

Comment: Ok i see what you did. This worked for me. You aligned everything with the 0. Im going to go under the assumption that I can add the space to the end here and it would work opposite.

Comment: Yea I read a bit on using `set::setw` for some reason I couldn't figure out how to get it to work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it directly with C++ streams and

```
 <iomanip>
```

using setwidth() and setfill() etc.

Take a look at the Jossutis' example here:

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n9VEG2Gp5pkC&pg=PA618&lpg=PA618&dq=josuttis+setwidth&source=bl&ots=Rem8pr98PT&sig=gxyrv39njxNvB1l8fyeLfCMMVfE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eU6nUqPdM4jE7Abp5IGgDA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=josuttis%20setwidth&f=false